# Get all Channels connected to a YouTube account

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

how can you get all youtube channels connected to an account? I used the service "youtube.channels.list" and set the parameter "mine = true" but I only get my first registered channel. Can anybody give me hints? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by connected? is it subscribed to a channel or as you owned? By setting the parameter to true, [you instruct the API to only return channels owned by the authenticated user](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#parameters).

Comment: Yeah I just found out. Thank you though. It's connected with your oauth access grant.