# How to get ALL Channels connected to a YouTube account and not only ONE

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-authentication

I want a way of selecting a YouTube channel through the Google authentication form. My problem is: when I call the method

$youtube->channels->listChannels(.., array('mine'=>'true'))

it returns only one channel, instead I have two channels and I would like the method to return me both or at least to let me choose between my channels. The weird thing is that the API explorers behave differently:

// Good behavior but I don't know how to implement it

If I make a request with this API Explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails%252Cstatistics&mine=true&_h=1&
It gives me the chance to select my YouTube channels in the Google login window.

// Bad behavior, I have implemented it

Instead, if I make the same request here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list, selecting 'list (channels managed by a content owner)' in the Usage section, The Google authentication window makes me choose only the Google Account and gives me always ONLY ONE channel.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the comment in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485983/get-all-channels-connected-to-a-youtube-account).

> What do you mean by connected? is it subscribed to a channel or as you
>   owned? By setting the parameter to true, [you instruct the API to only
>   return channels owned by the authenticated user](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#parameters).

You can refer here for [Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication).

> The YouTube Data API supports the [OAuth 2.0 protocol](http://oauth.net/2/) for
>   authorizing access to private user data.